# No module named numpy.core.multiarray

Tags: python, numpy, importerror

This is the script I am working with

```
# this script starts in powershell so I change the directory to Python27

os.chdir("/Python27/"

#print cwd as a check 
print os.getcwd()

import nltk

text = nltk.work_tokenize("thanks, Chuck and it's always nice when you get Brian's name corrected, it shows how closely we .....blah blah blah")

#print text as a check
print text

nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

The script will print text, but it is followed immediately by an Import Error

```
Import Error message is as follows;

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calls_1.txt", line 15, in <module>

     nltk.pos_tag(text)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 99, in pos_tag
    tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py"' line 605, in load 
    resource_val = pickle.load(_oopen(resource_url))

ImportError: No module named numpy.core.multiarray
```

However, it appears that the multiarray module is present. This is the result from `sys.path`

```
>>> for pth in sys.path:
...   print pth
...

C:windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Pthon27\DLLs
C:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
>>>
```

Within the `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages` directory there are the following directories:

```
nltk
nltk-2.0.4-py2.5.egg-info
numpy
yaml
yaml.pyd
PyYAML-3.10-py2.7.egg-info 
README.txt
```

within the numpy directory there are the following directories

```
core
fft
lib         
lnalg                 
random
```

within the core directory there are the following pyd files

```
_dotblas.pyd
_sort.pyd
multiarray.pyd
scalarmath.pyd
umath.pyd
```

So it appears that multiarray is present but is not found.

Any suggestions as to how I should proceed to correct the script is appreciated.

Comment: **Please**, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help